# Can't load Properties from JAR

Tags: java, properties, jar

For a few days now, I have been trying to get my Java project to load some properties from a file located in it's JAR file. However, I am constantly getting a null pointer when trying to load in the file.

The folder hierarchy has the properties file in /data, and all the source files in /emp/**/** ...

### Code

```
Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/build_info.properties");
        //InputStream in = new URL("file:data/build_info.properties").openStream();

        defaultProps.load(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.E("NPE- Properties not loaded", "properties");
        revision = "Properties file not found";
    }

    if (defaultProps.getProperty("build.major.number") == null) {
        Log.W("Properties not loaded", "properties");
        revision = "Properties file not found";
    } else {
        Log.V("Properties Loaded Successfully", "properties");
        
        revision = "Version: " + defaultProps.getProperty("build.major.number")
            + "." + defaultProps.getProperty("build.minor.number") + "    "
            + "Revision: "
            + defaultProps.getProperty("build.revision.number");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `data` is in the root of your jar, and if `build_info.properties` is inside the data directory in the jar, and if the jar is on the classpath, then `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/build_info.properties");` will find that properties file. You could also use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/build_info.properties");`.

Peculiarities can arise if `getClass()` returns a class loaded by a classloader different than the one that has your jar on its classpath.

Comment: I believe all of those things are true. How would i make sure that the JAR is on my classpath?

Comment: Hello? I could really use the help

Comment: One thing you could do in your program is try to use a class that's in that jar. If you get a NoClassDefFoundError or ClassNotFoundException (which one depends on exactly what you do), then it's not seeing things in that jar. Is this Android source? I don't know much about Android. If so, you should add an android tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively try --

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/build_info.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a dead-simple console application. Eventually I found a hint at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464541/1792291 and I made my console app into a swing app, and suddenly everything worked.

The explanation in the link above does make some sense: since the console app gets its properties (including CLASSPATH) once when the shell is created, it won't know about the classpath defined during/for/by the JVM.